# Store Kivy objects/ids in list

Tags: python, list, button, checkbox, kivy

I need to store kivy object id-s (and some other info) in a list, but it does`nt seeme to work with kivy.
there are checkboxes for every button, witch should enable/disable the buttons.
the enabling/disabling should happen after a button is pressed (not immediately, like id could be done in kv file)
I could write a punch of if,elif statements and it would work like that, but I will have a lot of buttons and different button lists so I would like to go through the checkboxses with for loop.

```
    #Here`s my python code:

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class MainLayout(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        chk1 = ObjectProperty(None)
        btn1 = ObjectProperty(None)
        chk2 = ObjectProperty(None)
        btn2 = ObjectProperty(None)
        chk3 = ObjectProperty(None)
        btn3 = ObjectProperty(None)
        chk4 = ObjectProperty(None)
        btn4 = ObjectProperty(None)

        #(checkbox id, button id, value)
        self.object_list = [(chk1, btn1, 1),
                            (chk2, btn2, 2),
                            (chk3, btn3, 3),
                            (chk4, btn4, 4)]


    def myfunc(self):
        for i in self.object_list:
            if i[0].active == True:
                i[1].disabled = False

            elif i[0].active == False:
                i[1].disabled = True



class CheckboxTestApp(App):
    pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    CheckboxTestApp().run()



#and here`s the .kv
MainLayout:

<MainLayout>:

    chk1 : chk1
    btn1 : btn1
    chk2 : chk2
    btn2 : btn2
    chk3 : chk3
    btn3 : btn3
    chk4 : chk4
    btn4 : btn4


    cols: 4
    CheckBox:
        id: chk1
        active: True
    Button:
        id: btn1
        text: '1'
        on_press: root.myfunc()

    CheckBox:
        id: chk2
        active: True
    Button:
        id: btn2
        text: '2'
        on_press: root.myfunc()

    CheckBox:
        id: chk3
        active: True
    Button:
        id: btn3
        text: '3'
        on_press: root.myfunc()

    CheckBox:
        id: chk4
        active: True
    Button:
        id: btn4
        text: '4'
        on_press: root.myfunc()
```

Comment: Aren't kivy properties supposed to be declared at [**class level**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#observe-property-changes) ?

Comment: I don`t really know, I have seen several methods, how to interact with kv ids (only not with using list, like I am trying to do) I am kind of new to kivy, (and also python) so forgive me, if the question is stupid.
also, result would be the same.

Comment: AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'active'

Comment: I think making mistakes while learning is quite a common thing. What's really important is that we shouldn't make the same mistake repeatedly as that suggests we aren't learning at all. However most often there are many ways to accomplish certain task, here perhaps you can use [**dynamic class**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#dynamic-classes) to make it easier to handle.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I`m not sure, this solves my problem, it`s definitely useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem using kivy built in dictionary ids.
I only updated the python code so here it is.

```
#python code
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class MainLayout(GridLayout):
    objects = [('chk1', 'btn1', 1),
               ('chk2', 'btn2', 2),
               ('chk3', 'btn3', 3),
               ('chk4', 'btn4', 4)]

    def myfunc(self):
        for i in self.objects:
            if self.ids[i[0]].active == True:
                self.ids[i[1]].disabled = False

            elif self.ids[i[0]].active == False:
                self.ids[i[1]].disabled = True





class CheckboxTestApp(App):
    pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    CheckboxTestApp().run()
```